# Python dictionary-like structure in C++?

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, templates, stdvector

In Python, I have a dict with unorganized keys/values with the values always being a list of different types:

```
my_dict = {'foo': [5, 3.0],
           'bar': ['foo', 'bar', 9.5]}
```

In Python, this is easy because it's not an explicitly typed language. I can just use whatever type I want in values. In C++, I have problem because std::maps/std::vectors have to be typed.

Basically, I want something like:
`std::map<std::string, std::vector<X> >`

X where I want to be able to have any number of types I want within the vector. My best guess is that a template can do it? I'm not sure. I just want a way to be able to have a map with some sort of data structure where I can use any type for a vector or array in a map value.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. If the list of possible types is limited, one can use the `std::variant` template, or use dynamic scope, and an object superclass, from which all possible subclasses derive from, and provide some abstract methods to do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: Did you check std::any, i.e. std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::any>>

Comment: @Nitesh I don't have c++17  (or boost for its any)

Comment: You can download [Boost](https://www.boost.org/), and there are many free compilers like [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) and [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) that support C++17.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there is `std::unordered_map` it is the parallel variant of the Python's dictionary, i.e., both use hashing.

For `std::vector<X>` you simply need a type `X` that can store any value type you want. In C++17 there is `std::any` and `std::variant` for storing any type. Or you can find their implementations elsewhere.

If you don't mind some overhead you can simply use `std::tuple` or use a simple structure with an enum that identifies what it is.

```
enum class MyType
{
   UNDEFINED, INT, DOUBLE, STRING
}

struct MyData
{
    MyType mType = MyType::UNDEFINED;
    int mInt;
    double mDouble;
    std::string mString;
}
```

Comment: One question. std::tuple requires specifying the type, so how would that work in an std::unordered_map with different types of tuples?

Comment: @J.Doe you need from the start to choose the enabled types, e.g., `std::tuple<int,double,string>` you cannot store inside such a tuple anything other than these three variables.